# Jwplayer for element inside kendo Editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio, kendo-ui, jwplayer

i have used **kendoui**,In html editor of kendoui i add custom tool for audio integration and for audio i am using **jwplayer**,
when creating player for div inside editor it gives error Uncaught `TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'setup'`

i want to create jwplayer dive inside of kendo editor is it possible ?
if yes then how ?

Comment: @EthanLongTail sory sir,we haven't deployed application yet. but i had use jwplayer to add audio file into editor content(like html editor).

Comment: Is there a way we can debug this then?

Comment: Greate we have hosted for testing have look at http://cfstaging.promactinfo.com/Project/Index (afrer registration and login) in there story page there is kendo editor and use custom tools in that for audio.  Please i am really stuck in this issue.

Comment: Can I have a temp log in to use?

Comment: yeah...nileshmordiya@promactinfo.com/Nill@007

Comment: I am in now, but I only see one player which is YouTube?

Comment: i have no problem with video but i want to use it in audio,as reason for stable version of application we have not used jwplayer right now because we had above issue.  may i know where are u adding it ???

Comment: We don't have any official support for kendo. I wanted to see a link to where you attempted to embed the player so I could troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: Thanx for your time but  now i have no longer need for that...as we only support HTML5 enable browsers and we use audio tags for that.

Comment: Np. The JW Player supports HTML5 by default.